Building an interrogative sentence with both a pronoun and a subject
What is the correct word order in German, when building a question that contains both a pronoun (as accusative or dativ object) and a noun (as subject) ? For instance, if I want to translate the sentence "Is this meeting important for you?", which of the following translations is correct/allowed/usual ?

Ist dir dieser Termin wichtig?
Ist dieser Termin dir wichtig?
Ist dieser Termin wichtig für dich?

Based on the "adDA"-rule, I would instinctively go for (1) or (3), but it looks somewhat strange in (1) to put the dative object BEFORE the subject... I looked in various grammar books but unfortunately I could not find an answer that brought me certainty.

All of your examples are correct. There are lots of answers about word order here. Please use the searching function.

Thanks @Olafant, that helps a lot! I had used the search function but for some reason it did not get me to this "Order of words" question. Herzlichen Dank!
